Have eslint be quiet when a glob pattern finds no files
Not sure if this is an eslint, yarn or glob question, but I think it is about glob patterns.
In package.json I have two "scripts" entries, one to run eslint --fix, the other to run mocha tests.
"scripts": {
 "test": "yarn run lintfixjs && mocha --recursive",
 "lintfixjs": "eslint --fix *.js tools/*.js other_tools/*.js lib/*.js"
}

It has been working fine for years, on developer machines. The problem comes when I went to run yarn test on a cut-down server install, which didn't have the "tools/" and "other_tools/" directories. I get:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

No files matching the pattern "tools/*.js" were found.

My Question: Is there a way to say "tools/*.js if tools exists otherwise []" when giving commandline arguments?

I don't want to change "tools/*.js" to "tools/" (though that also doesn't work) and I don't want to change what yarn test and yarn lintfixjs does for developers.
My best idea is to make a new scripts entry:
 "test_cutdown":"eslint --fix *.js lib/*.js && mocha --recursive",

That is workable, I just wondered if there was another way.
